# Setting commerce sales price with views

Tags: commerce

I am trying to set up a sale price on certain products on a drupal site, however from the project page of commerce_saleprice there is this patch https://drupal.org/files/commerce-views_precalculated_price-1020050-5.patch that should be applied but am stack because i dont know to which module this has to be applied as i tried applying it to commerce_saleprice and it fails.

My requirement is to put some products on sale and then call them in a view... any insight on this, i already have price savings formatters installed.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the patch file it needs to be applied to commerce_price -

cd to /sites/all/modules/commerce (or wherever you have the commerce module) and a command like this should do it:

```
patch -p1 < /path/to/file.patch
```

And then write down what you've done so you don't forget next time you update the commerce module ;)

Comment: Well thanks for the tip i actually have added the patch at sites/all/modules/commerce the its seems not to be applying properly

i get the following output 
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file modules/price/commerce_price.info.rej

Comment: When you see this error, it is almost always because you're using a patch for the wrong version of the code you're patching. There are a few ways to work around this:
1. Get the new version of the module and apply the patch
2. apply it manually